# Hidden files in Document Set Library based on custom field on SharePoint List Lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, document-set

I have a Document Set Library with a lookup column to a SharePoint list. Please note it is a Document ***SET*** library, not a standard Document library.

The issue: Some files within a document set folder are hidden. They are there, but are hidden. I've troubleshooted all I know to do:

1. No filters are set on the view
2. No manual filters applied
3. Files are not deleted
4. All applicable settings to show all files are turned on

Discovery: On the SharePoint list I created a custom field to capture an overall status of OPEN or CLOSED. What I found was that the files are hidden if the SharePoint list item that the Document Set library Lookup column is set to has a status of CLOSED. I've never heard of a custom field dictating this behavior before. I have no settings, filters or workflows tied to this custom status field. It's as if SharePoint is it's own A.I. and perceives the linked List Item to be closed, and therefore decides to hide my files.

What is causing this custom field to dictate hiding files in a linked Document Set Library and how can I stop it from doing so?